# Latest version of Firefox won't work in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, firefox, linux-mint

Since yesterday Firefox won't start when I click on the icon. I'm running Linux Mint 14 in VirtualBox. I think it's trying to update to version 39.0.3.
In a terminal I get

> firefox -safe-mode
>   Error: Platform version '39.0.3' is not compatible with minVersion >= 39.0 maxVersion <= 39.0

Is there something I can do (update a configuration file?) to make this work?
Thanks for any help